# Checking conditions using Automapper

Tags: c#, lambda, automapper

I am using Automapper. In that, I mapped the DTO with the database table. In that one, I need to check one condition and then take the value.

```
CreatedBy = mapper.Map<UserProperties>((from createdByUser in context.persons.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Id == notes.CreatedBy) select createdByUser).FirstOrDefault())
```

This is my code.

User Properties Class:

```
public string DisplayName { get; set; }

public int Id { get; set; }

public bool IsUser { get; set; }

public int NotesCount {get;set;}
```

Persons

```
public string DisplayName { get; set; }

public int Id { get; set; }

public int RoleId{ get; set; }

public int NotesCount {get;set;}

public string Notes{get;set;}

public string Comments {get;set;}
```

The below code is the automapper configuration in the start up file.

[image]

Mapping Profile Class

[image]

In persons, have the field `roleId`. I need to assign the values for the `IsUser` field in the User properties class by checking the condition like `RoleId` field in Persons is equal to 2.

How to Check the condition using the automapper?

Automapper Version: 9.0.0

Comment: Can you show your AutoMapper config code

Comment: I added the config code in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `ForMember` clause to your mapping to add the condition - here's a working example (which took longer than it should have, because you posted an image of your code instead of the actual code. This is why on SO you should always post code, not images.)

```cs
void Main()
{
    var mapperConfig = 
          new MapperConfiguration(mc => mc.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());

    var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
    var notAUser = new Persons { RoleId = 1};
    var isAUser = new Persons { RoleId = 2};

    var shouldBeNotAUser = mapper.Map<UserProperties>(notAUser);
    var shouldBeAUser = mapper.Map<UserProperties>(isAUser);

    Console.WriteLine(shouldBeNotAUser.IsUser);
    Console.WriteLine(shouldBeAUser.IsUser);

}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Persons, UserProperties>()
        .ForMember(destination => destination.IsUser, 
                     options => options.MapFrom(src => src.RoleId == 2));
    }
}

class UserProperties
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsUser { get; set; }
    public int NotesCount { get; set; }
}

class Persons
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int NotesCount { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

> False
>   True

### However

Your mapping configuration code should not have to 'know' about what RoleID indicates a user. Your `Person` class should be where that knowledge is held, so that should have either an `IsUser()` method or a get-only `IsUser` property (with the `NotMapped` attribute) which returns `RoleId == 2`: in the former case you would still need `ForMember` but in the latter case you wouldn't, though if you *do* map back from `UserProperties` to `Persons` you would need something there to handle it - again, this should be in the `Persons` class and not in the mapper config. Maybe `SetAsUser()` that sets the RoleId.